# jQuery Unbind Unnamed Functions

Tags: function, unbind

How can I unbind this mousemove event specifically? I know how to unbind event handlers that are given to specific elements, but how do i unbbind a single event handler function when using $(this)?

```
$(this).on("mousemove", function() {

});
```

Comment: are you using this as a first child of $(document).ready(...) or in some other function?

Comment: Its within a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$(this).unbind('mousemove');
```

Works?